# How to limit a fixed banner's height to 50% of the screen while keeping it fully visible when scrolling?

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed banner at the bottom of my webpage, and I want to limit its height to 50% of the screen height. However, I also want to ensure that the banner remains fully visible and does not get partially hidden when I scroll the main content.

I've tried using max-height: 50vh; for the banner, but the problem is that when I scroll the main content, the banner scrolls with it, and the bottom of the banner becomes hidden.

Here's my current CSS for the banner:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.wrapper > p {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.banner {
  max-height: 50vh;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}

.banner-title {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Bebas Neue Bold", sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.7rem;
  line-height: 1.25926;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.banner-container {
  background-color: blue;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.banner-inner {
  width: calc(100% - 8.33333%);
  margin-left: 4.16667%;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.banner-privacy {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}

.banner-privacy > p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  line-height: 1.71429;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  max-height: 6rem;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
  color: grey;
  float: none;
  position: relative;
}

.banner-btn-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: -1em;
}

.banner-btn {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-color: grey;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  font-family: "PT Sans Bold", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  min-width: min-content;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.8em 1.9em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <main class="wrapper">
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>last Hello</p>
    <div class="banner">
      <div class="banner-container">
        <div class="banner-inner">
          <div class="banner-title">
            Cookie Banner
          </div>
          <div class="banner-privacy">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed fugit amet porro labore iure adipisci quasi
              reprehenderit, tempora voluptas placeat cumque, eligendi dolorum laborum reiciendis, deleniti eaque!
              Mollitia, eius cupiditate?</p>
          </div>
          <div class="banner-btn-wrapper">
            <button class="banner-btn">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</button>
            <button class="banner-btn">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</button>
            <button class="banner-btn">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Another problem I faced setting `position: fixed`, that bottom of the banner goes off the screen and last 5-6 `p` elements will overflow behind the banner.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior where the banner's height is limited to 50% of the screen but remains fully visible even when scrolling? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: _"behavior where the banner's height is limited to 50% of the screen but remains fully visible"_ - those two demands are conflicting with either other. You can't have it both ways. At most you could allow the content _inside_ the banner to create a scrollbar, if its height is bigger than the 50vh.

Comment: What if the content of the banner won't fit into half the screen? Do you want the banner to independently scrollable, or do you want to simply truncate any overflow?

Comment: @BrettDonald I want to truncate any overflow.

Comment: @CBroe makes sense. 
The content inside the banner can't be scrollbar. 
Does it mean in this case that the only solution would be reduce the height of the elements inside the banner to make it visible on small breakpoints?

Comment: As the user can make the viewport as small as they like I can't see how you can avoid allowing scrolling of the banner at some point.

Comment: @AHaworth reducing the banner height?

Comment: Well, you can reduce the banner height, but then it might not be tall enough for the content - as @CBroe points out.

Comment: So what you guys think, would be the most optimal solution here?

Comment: Dispense with the cookie banner entirely. I’ve never understood why websites offer cookie choices, because (a) it's an annoying interruption, (b) most users don't understand the implications, (c) I don't trust the website to restrict its use of cookies in response to my input, and (d) my browser gives me the ability to block cookies if I really need to.

Comment: @BrettDonald isn't it a requirement in some regions to have the cookie usage made plain to the user?

Comment: @BrettDonald :)

Answer (score 1):

For myself, I'd prefer something minimalist near one of the corners.

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body, button {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

.wrapper > p {
  padding: 2rem;
}

.banner {
  position: fixed;
  right: 1em;
  bottom: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}

.banner p {
  margin: 0;
}

.banner p:first-child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.banner p:last-child {
  margin-top: 0.6em;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1em;
  justify-content: center;
}

.banner a {
  color: inherit;
}

.banner button {
  padding: 3px 10px;
  border: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.banner button:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<main class="wrapper">
    <p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p><p>Hello</p>
    <p>last Hello</p>
</main>
<div class="banner" onclick="this.remove()">
  <p>x</p>
  <p>This site <a href="https://www.justsotasty.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Chocolate-Chip-Cookie-for-One-24-500x375.jpg" title="click for more info">uses cookies</a>.</p>
  <p><button>Accept</button><button>Reject</button></p>
</div>
```

Stack Overflow has a wordier version which displays in the centre ... click the Cookie Settings link in the footer at the bottom of this page.

If you really need lots of space, maybe an overlay which uses 100% height might be better than 100% width. [This UK site](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/direct-marketing-and-privacy-and-electronic-communications/guide-to-pecr/guidance-on-the-use-of-cookies-and-similar-technologies/) is a good example. This design naturally mobile-friendly, too.

[image]

I do feel for anyone having to comply with website cookie regulations. Perhaps [this perpsective](https://silktide.com/blog/sick-of-cookie-banners-and-popups-theyre-all-changing-again/) will keep you smiling.